# How to fix this: cannot create user in Windows 8

Tags: user, windows-8.1

On the computer of my son (Windows 8.1) I have a problem that appeared after handling and moved some files of the programs menu.

Here's what happened:

I created a user "School" because he will use his computer at school and I have to limit some accesses to softwares on that account. So I moved a lot of links that were in user "default" to another account that he used to play on this computer (called "player"). that other account have admin priviledges. As a precaution, I wanted to create another `Administrator account` (just in case), but now, from the account "player" that has admin rights, I cannot create new user anymore:

- From "Control Panel" "Users management" when I click the link to create a new account, nothing happens.
- From "Computer Management" (C:\WindowsSystem32\mmc.exe compmgmt.msc) I see nothing to manage users and groups of users, from the list below "Tools systems"
  I guess I made a mistake, but I do not know how to repair, does someone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not touch the default Account. It seems like you have broken this, so imagine, the default is a template account and all other accounts are created with this informations. So now you destroyed the account and cant create new accounts. You have to install Windows new (this is the best way) or you try to make the changes undone.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to undone, so. Can you tell me if there is some differences between windows 7 and 8.1 in default user content ? To compare with another computer... (Windows 8 was pre-installed on the computer when I bought it, I don't know how to reinstall it)

Comment: so u destroyed 2 pcs? :D i dont think that there are big differents. but if u want to limit some privileges at the computers again, open a new question and contact me with the limitits so we can help u :) Because windows 7 and upper have so many options to limit - you only must find out where and what you want ...greats

Comment: Thank you again. No, the other Windows 7 PC works fine. So I would like to compare with to see what are the differences, in order to repair the damaged windows 8.

Comment: hmm. with windows 8 microsoft started to sync the profildata with the online accounts and so on. but i dont know if this matters

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by another way. As an admin, I run the following from `cmd.exe`:

```
net user administrator /active:yes
```

Now the account "Administrator" can be used to log in and have admin rights. It also have availability to create new users.